# Activiti / Java - Is there a way to change how Activiti formats dates and times?

Tags: java, jsp, activiti

I'm working on a web project that outputs task info. Is there a way to change how times are outputted or change what time-zone is used? Specifically within Activiti itself so I don't have to change the formatting within my JSP pages. I couldn't find anything about it in the user-guide so I'm hoping that there's someone else out there who's done something similar to what I'm trying to do. I'm a novice at Java so forgive me if I'm missing something obvious.

EDIT:
I currently output my dates using JSTL, like so:

```
<fmt:formatDate pattern="dd-MMM-yyyy HH:mm:ss z" value="${process.getStartTime()}" />
```

So basically, instead of having to add this "fmt" tag each time, is there a method or something in Activiti that allows you to change how dates are formatted? And also, change the time-zone.

Comment: explain pls you you currently output your dates in jsp and what is the desired result. As it stands your question is too vague to be answered

Comment: @MaVRoSCy I've edited the question, hopefully it's clearer.